# How to optimize queries in django-admin? Too many sql queries because of foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset, django-orm

I have model of product and category:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

In admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_editable = ('name', 'category')
```

When I go to admin page there are too many duplicated SQL queries, all of them getting categories. If i remove category from list_editable, all duplicated queries disappear.

I tried to do this:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(ProductAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).select_related('category')
    return qs
```

It doesn't work.